# Polymorphic default function argument

Tags: types, polymorphism, ocaml, optional-parameters

Is there a way to avoid rewriting functions like the following to apply to multiple types?

In this example, could I write the optional function `f_comp` in such a way to avoid the necessity of writing two functions?

Example:

```
module M = Map.Make (String)
module S = Set.Make (String)
let m = M.add "a" (S.of_list ["a"; "b"]) M.empty
      |> M.add "b" (S.of_list ["a"])

let h_highest_degree ?(f_comp=(>)) a b g : bool =
  f_comp (S.cardinal (M.find a g)) (S.cardinal (M.find b g))

(* Can I avoid need to define this function? *)
let h_highest_degree_f ?(f_comp=(>)) a b g =
  f_comp (float_of_int (S.cardinal (M.find a g)))
    (float_of_int (S.cardinal (M.find b g)))

(* e.g *)
h_highest_degree "a" "b" m
```

They both seem to have the same type signatures to me, aside from the default function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative definition you could have given for `h_highest_degree_f` which doesn't duplicate as much as the definition for `h_highest_degree`:

```
let h_highest_degree_f ?(f_comp=(>)) a b g =
  h_highest_degree a b g
    ~f_comp:(fun x y -> f_comp (float_of_int x) (float_of_int y))

(* h_highest_degree_f : ?f_comp:(float -> float -> bool) -> string -> string -> S.t M.t -> bool *)
```

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're asking, though. You say that you're looking for a way to "avoid rewriting functions like the following to apply to multiple types." But there is no function that's being used at multiple types in your program. `f_comp` in `h_highest_degree` has the type `int -> int -> bool` (because `S.cardinal (M.find a g)` and `S.cardinal (M.find b g)` both have type `int`, and the return type of the function is explicitly annotated as type `bool`). Since `S.cardinal (M.find a g)` and `S.cardinal (M.find b g)` are hardwired into your definition of `h_highest_degree`, I'm not sure how `f_comp` could have any type but `int -> int -> bool`. If my response doesn't answer your question, could you perhaps give another example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: yea, you're right, I ended up using essentially the following basis function (not particularly useful) to solve my problem: `let h_fn ?(cmp=h_cmp) f (a:'a) (b:'a) g : bool = cmp (f a g) (f b g)`